# NEST API, custom_filters_score how to use it in the query?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I need to boost the score of a match based on a field that is not searched on. ElasticSearch lets you do it using "custom_filters_score". I am using NEST API and I am not sure if this is supported or if there is an alternative to this? The documentation is not very helpful on this aspect.
http://nest.azurewebsites.net/query/custom-filters-score.html

Is there a way using NEST querying API other than falling back on RawQuery?

Answer (score 0):

A pull request for this has been send for this: https://github.com/Mpdreamz/NEST/pull/237

Which will make it into the next release.